# How to install only the specified package and missing dependencies with pip from a local directory?

Tags: python, pip

I have downloaded a python package (a .whl file) and the dependencies that are not already installed on the system to a local directory. I want to then use pip to install from that directory the desired package and the dependencies that are not already installed. I am using `pip install` with `--no-index` and `--find-links`. However, for any dependencies that are not in the local find-links directory, even if already installed, pip fails with an error like:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement of requirement_name>=n.n (from module)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requirement_name>=n.n
```

The requirement `requirement_name` with a valid version is already installed. This is verified by running `pip show requirement_name`. Since a package for `requirement_name` is not in the directory specified by `--find-links`, pip fails. Is there a way to make pip ignore the packages that are already installed?

For example I want to install `d_module.whl` and with dependencies `a_module`, `b_module` and `c_module`. `a_module` is already installed with the correct version `1.2`, so I download `b_module.whl`, `c_module.whl`, and `d_module.whl` and put them in the directory `/downloads`. I run `pip install --no-index --find-links file:///downloads d_module`. pip would fail with this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement of a_module>=1.1 (from d_module)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for a_module>=1.1
```

```
$ pip show a_module
Name: a_module
Version: 1.2
Summary: a cool python module
...
Location: /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages
```

Comment: I find that pip does an extraordinarily poor job with updating existing installations. Generally recommend only pip installing once into a new venv with the complete list of packages that you want.